# Need help understanding my voltage measurements

Tags: voltage, batteries, step-down

I have a device connected to a power source (2 AA batteries hooked to a DC-DC step down buck, set to 2.5V).

When the device is connected, I read 2.2 V on the output of the buck. When it is not connected, I read 2.5V on the output.

Now, I need 2.5V for my device, which reading is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2.5 V reading is correct, **unloaded**.  But when you connect the device, its load likely is too much for your buck converter to supply at full voltage.  You might consider a circuit or buck converter that can supply -- with some margin left over -- the requirements of your connected device.

Comment: Well, the device draws 40 mA. It can't be that. Maybe the batteries are empty?

Comment: Possibly.  Flat batteries might read the right reading with the nearly-zero load your multimeter puts on them but drop precitously with any real load.